# capture all insert update events in c# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc ,entitiy framework and sql db  for my application.I want to create one method like a filter as event listener for all the insert update delete events in the mvc application.Is there any suggestions for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to learn about SQL Server Triggers. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Or you can use the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Triggers/ for pure C# solution (I don't know it, I just googled for EF Core Triggers)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman i want to listen to those events from c# application

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom Filter and decorate with it the actions or controllers you want, something like this:

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {   
            //In case you need it to log which one has been accessed for example
            Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

            //Do your code...

            //Continue to the action
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```